# Fail to register ISO or template on cloudstack

Tags: templates, user-interface, iso, ready, apache-cloudstack

A problem occurs when I register an ISO or template on Apache CloudStack.

When I finished and submitted the register ISO form, no error message occurs.  However, if I inspect the template, the result in the "ready" field is "no" and the "status" field is empty!  I can't create an instance because I can't register my own ISO or template.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and my system VMs are already in running! So, I just don't know why. Would you please to help me?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply!I have worked on it for many days,and I have tried many ways,but the situation is even worse.The current problem is show as below:                                                      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585911/cloudstack-fail-to-start-primary-and-second-storage

Comment: I am having the similar problem. But in my case no system VM is showing under infrastructure link in cloudstack management UI. why is that? I got no error when setting up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We faced similar problem and to resolved the issue:-

1) Went to SSVM,Stoped the cloud service .

2) On SSVM tried to run the run script

3) cd /usr/local/cloud/systemvm/

4) ./run.sh

5) There it was showing error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vmware/vim25/VirtualDevice
at com.cloud.storage.resource.VmwareSecondaryStorageResourceHandler.<init>(VmwareSecondaryStorageResourceHandler.java:61)
at com.cloud.storage.resource.PremiumSecondaryStorageResource.configure(PremiumSecondaryStorageResource.java:102)
at com.cloud.agent.Agent.<init>(Agent.java:163)
at com.cloud.agent.AgentShell.launchAgent(AgentShell.java:559)
at com.cloud.agent.AgentShell.launchAgentFromClassInfo(AgentShell.java:514)
at com.cloud.agent.AgentShell.launchAgent(AgentShell.java:431)
at com.cloud.agent.AgentShell.start(AgentShell.java:589)
at com.cloud.agent.AgentShell.main(AgentShell.java:631)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vmware.vim25.VirtualDevice
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 8 more
```

6) We found that file  "vmware-vim25.jar" was missing, so we copied that Jar file  to (/usr/local/cloud/systemvm/) of SSVM from management server location (/usr/share/java/vmware-vim25.jar)

7) restart cloud service and its worked.

8) We followed comment of (Sateesh Chodapuneedi added a comment - 05/Mar/13 15:00 ) in following link:-
Reference:-  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CLOUDSTACK-1252

Answer (score 2):

The GUI **feedback you see is normal**:

Template creation, whether is based on an ISO or a virtual disk, is an async task.  With all asynchronous tasks, CloudStack takes some time to produce an answer.  Therefore, you have to check back *after* the call to see if it failed.

Have a close **look at the log file** to see the exact cause.

Here are some **possibilities:**

- Upload from an internal IP address is disabled.

By default, CloudStack does not allow templates to be uploaded from an IP address in the CloudStack subnet.

You can enable uploads using the global settings.  Search for 'internal'.

- System VM templates have not been added to your management server.

During installation, there is a step that involves manually adding the system VM template to CloudStack.  Without this template, CloudStack cannot create the secondary storage system vm (SSVM) responsible for adding templates to secondary storage.

Check that an SSVM has been created on one of the hypervisors in the zone you configured.

- Secondary storage is not properly setup

If the permissions or secondary storage server is not setup correctly, the SSVM will not be to copy new templates into secondary storage.

Check that you are able to mount secondary storage on your CloudStack management server.  This will give you an indication of whether the share you are using for secondary storage is exported properly.

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve this problem by changing global settings->secstorage.allowed.internal.sites to 192.168.1.50/0. Where my ip address is 192.168.1.50.