# Fail to register iso template on cloudstack(2)

Tags: iso, apache-cloudstack

Now I can start 2 system VMs in cloudstack 4.0. However, it comes back to the old problem that I am unable to register iso or template. This very strange that there are two system VMs displaying on UI but I get the log infomation:

```
2013-10-26 10:52:36,894 DEBUG [storage.secondary.SecondaryStorageManagerImpl] (secstorage-1:null) Zone 1 is not ready to launch secondary storage VM yet
2013-10-26 10:52:36,979 DEBUG [cloud.consoleproxy.ConsoleProxyManagerImpl] (consoleproxy-1:null) Zone 1 is not ready to launch console proxy yet
2013-10-26 10:52:37,370 DEBUG [network.router.VirtualNetworkApplianceManagerImpl] (RouterStatusMonitor-1:null) Found 0 routers.
2013-10-26 10:52:47,345 DEBUG [cloud.server.StatsCollector] (StatsCollector-1:null) HostStatsCollector is running...
2013-10-26 10:52:47,366 DEBUG [cloud.server.StatsCollector] (StatsCollector-2:null) StorageCollector is running...
2013-10-26 10:52:47,369 DEBUG [cloud.server.StatsCollector] (StatsCollector-2:null) There is no secondary storage VM for secondary storage host nfs://172.17.4.102/export/secondary
```

What happens? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I doubt if this is a programming question..

Comment: This seems more of a CloudStack admin / user question, because you don't seem to be actively developing.  Have you tried the [Apache CloudStack users mailing list](http://cloudstack.apache.org/mailing-lists.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about NFS issue, try NFS 3 in ubuntu environment.

Answer (score 1):

Put your storage machine and SSVM in same Local Area Network. And then try to register.

Comment: From UI,I can see SSVM is already in the host that locates in the same subnet with management server machine.But there are still warning in the management server log that "Zone 1 is not ready to launch secondary storage VM and console proxy yet and There is no secondary storage VM for secondary storage host nfs://172.17.4.102/export/secondary".And there is no log record in agent.log.It's so strange!I wonder where does the SSVM should locate in?The mangement server or the host running hypervisor?I know you are kindhearted,BUT I have not enough "repuation" to vote your answers.