# cloudstack console vm not starting

Tags: apache

I just now installed cloudstack all things are fine while i attempted to create a new instance it show null list of templats and i cheked console proxy vm it was stoped when i tried to start it not starting can any one help me i was googling since morning

i found that secondary memory is not sufficient but i added two more nfs servers to cloudstack but i again failed to start console proxy

i upgraded the kvm template which is /export/secondary/templat folder i was new to this

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have seeded secondary storage with the system VM template.

[Here is an explanation of how.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19586599/939250)